# Django Admin: when displaying an object, display a URL that contains one of the fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Here is an abstract base class for many of my "`Treatment`" models (`TreatmentA, TreatmentB`, etc):

```
class TreatmentBase(models.Model):
    URL_PREFIX = '' # child classes define this string

    code = shared.models.common.RandomCharField(length=6) 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Each `Treatment` instance has a URL, that when visited by a user, takes them to a page specific to that treatment. I want to be able to create a Treatment in Django Admin, and immediately get this URL so I can send it to users. This URL can be created with the following method on TreatmentBase:

```
    def get_url(self):
        return '{}/{}/'.format(self.URL_PREFIX, self.code)
```

However, I am stuck with how to get this URL to display in Django Admin. I can think of the following solutions:

(1) Customize the display of the `code` field so that it becomes a clickable URL. **Problem**: I don't know how to do this.

(2) Add the `get_url` method to `ModelAdmin.list_display`. **Problem**: This means I would have to define a separate `list_display` for each of the child models of `BaseTreatment`, and I would have to explicitly list all the fields of the model, meaning I have to update it every time I modify a model, violating DRY.

(3) Add an extra field like this:

```
    url = models.URLField(default = get_url)
```

Problem: `get_url` is an instance method (since it needs to refer to the `self.code` field), and from my reading of the [docs about the default argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default), it just has to be a simple callable without arguments.

Any way to do this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with option 2 (adding to the admin display) but add it to the 
[`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) which may alleviate your DRY concerns when models changes.

Option 3 (the extra field) could also work if you override the [`save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) method setting the URL property. You'd either want to set the field as readonly in the admin or only set the value in the `save` method if it's currently `None`.